# Getting error as Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: No event hubs for strategy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have implemented the Raft network with TLS with three orderer and installed and initiated Go chaincode however when I am trying to invoke chaincode its giving me error

```
error: [AbstractStrategy]: constructor: No event hubs for strategy
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: No event hubs for strategy
```

Please anybody help me as I am getting this issue first time.

Thanks in advance